# Creating a shortcut triggered by Modifier Key + Scroll

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I've been trying to map actions in keyboard shortcuts to be triggered by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll down</kbd>. However, it looks as if scrolling isn't considered valid as the second part of a shortcut. Is there a solution that will allow me to accomplish this? Preferably one that doesn't require AutoHotkey?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @PRATAP Sorry, edited to include my os version. And I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question? I'm talking about scrolling with the mouse, not with keys.

Comment: 0h thats a good point.. scrolling with mouse buttons cant be assigned from keyboard shortcuts.. you can use `xbindkeys` to use as combination of alt+mose button 4 and alt+mouse button 5 which are scroll down and scroll up..

Comment: @PRATAP switching workspaces up/down, thanks for your comment I'm looking into xbindkeys now.

Comment: @PRATAP I figured it out, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution! The following will do the trick using xbindkeys:

```
# Workspace up
"xdotool set_desktop $(expr $(expr $(xdotool get_desktop) + 1) % $(xdotool get_num_desktops))"
   Alt+b:5

# Workspace down
"xdotool set_desktop $(expr $(expr $(xdotool get_desktop) + $(expr $(xdotool get_num_desktops) - 1)) % $(xdotool get_num_desktops))"
   Alt+b:4
```

Got the commands from [here](https://defuse.ca/blog/linux-switch-virtual-desktop-workspace-mouse-button.html)

Comment: great job!! and s0 quick..